# ESLint: please spacify Node.js interpreter (не получается указать на Linux Mint)

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, linux-mint

PHPStorm в каждом окне выдает варнинг:

> ESLint: please spacify Node.js interpreter

У меня система Linux Mint. Везде пишут, что надо указать путь usr/local/bin/node, но у меня нет папки local.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

which node показывает

> snap/bin/node

, но по факту структура в папке snap совсем другая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал также установить последнюю актуальную версию, по рекомендации одного из комментов ниже:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Установщик выдает ошибки:

> - apt-get update Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
>   Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
>   Get:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4 502 B]
>   Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
>   Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114
>   kB] Ign:7 http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana InRelease       Hit:8
>   http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana Release         Err:4
>   https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease           The following
>   signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client
>   Repository se-um@microsoft.com Reading package lists... Done
>   W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The
>   following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype
>   Linux Client Repository se-um@microsoft.com E: The repository
>   'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed. N:
>   Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is
>   therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for
>   repository creation and user configuration details. Error executing
>   command, exiting

Comment: В первую очередь убедитесь, что у вас вообще установлен `nodejs`. Если он установлен, то у вас на скриншоте папка `usr` видна, в ней первая папка `bin`. Проверьте в ней наличие папки `node` или `nodejs` и выберите ее. Если nodejs не установлен, сначала установите его через менеджер пакетов

Comment: @VenZell нод установлен, а папки или файла в bin нет

Comment: откройте терминал и спросите `which node` или `which nodejs`

Comment: @VenZell snap/bin/node. А по факту в папке snap находится папка node, в которой есть еще 3 пустые папки 4933, common и current. Попробовал также эксекютить код установки из коммента ниже. Закончилось множественными ошибками

Comment: Добавьте уточнения в вопрос. Что находится в папке, какие ошибки при установке и т.д.

Comment: @VenZell обновил тему

Comment: Так у вас папка `/snap/bin/node` показана в консоли, а вы открыли `/home/user/snap`. Это разве одно и то же?

Comment: Как избавится от ошибки при установке я указал в ответе.

Comment: @VenZell переустановил node, теперь консоль показывает /usr/bin/node. В данной папке ничего не появилось. Как теперь указать нод интерпретатор?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти где установлен <kbd>Node.js</kbd> вы можете воспользоваться одной из следующих команд:

```bash
which node
```

или

```bash
which nodejs
```

Чтобы найти, где установлен <kbd>npm</kbd> вы можете воспользоваться командой:

```bash
which npm
```

Если с помощью этих команд найти программы не удалось, значит при их установке что-то пошло не так. Установите их снова. Пример ниже дан для установки последней актуальной версии:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Кроме того, у вас устарел ключ подписи для репозитория. Его обновление производится только в ручном режиме.

Выполните команду, указанную ниже, чтобы удалить устаревший ключ:

```
sudo apt-key del 1F3045A5DF7587C3
```

И следующую команду, чтобы добавить актуальный ключ:

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо, внес правки. Давно в последний раз ставил на Linux Node.js.